# How to render inline SVG from sanity?

Tags: sanity

I'm trying to render an inline SVG from the .svg file uploaded to sanity. I have tried with both image and file fields but it doesn't seem to supply the inline code

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

you need to use a package

```
npm i @focus-reactive/sanity-plugin-inline-svg-input
```

you can use it to upload svg files to your sanity studio

> in your sanity.config.js file:

```
import { inlineSvgInput } from '@focus-reactive/sanity-plugin-inline-svg-input'

plugins: [ inlineSvgInput() ]
```

> to preview svg's in your React or Next.js app:

```
import { InlineSvgPreviewComponent } from '@focus-reactive/sanity-plugin-inline-svg-input'

<InlineSvgPreviewComponent value={value} />
```